# Importing ".aar" file in Kotlin Multiplatform

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, kotlin-multiplatform

Thank you in advance for your time! I have been playing around KMP for a few weeks, trying to replicate a project, but i have been blocked for days trying to import an “.aar” into de multiplatform project, what i’m trying to do is make it accessible from android code so i can use that library. I placed the “.aar” file into the libs folder, then imported in the androidMain dependencies like :

```
implementation(files("./libs/spotify-app-remote-release-0.7.2.aar"))
```

i also added the following code into the settings.gradle.kts

```
flatDir {
    dirs("libs")
}
```

if i run the command androidDependences i see this entry (which i suspect that means that its included)

```
/Users/XXXXX/AndroidStudioProjects/kmp/YYYY/composeApp/libs/spotify-app-remote-release-0.7.2.aar
```

The thing is that when it comes to the kotlin code, i **cannot import the library** neither use it. I don’t know what i’m **doing wrong or what i'm missing**. If someone can throw some light would love them forever